# Firestore tab fragment recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been studying Firestore and trying to use it for the project. Realtime Database is easy to implement because I have a sample project that uses tab and recycler view, but Firestore is in difficulty because there is only a sample called friendly-eat. The realtime database sample also uses a library called com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Is firestore possible? I want to apply it to firestore like the existing RTDB. If anyone knows what I'm talking about, help me figure out how to apply it.

Question: Give me direction to make tabLayout - fragmentPagerAdapter + recyclerview + firestore

Comment: You'll have to move a lot of the code from the activity in the example to a fragment.

Comment: For future visitors, you can take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)**, where I have explained step by step how to display data from Firestore into a `RecyclerView` using Android.